# Analyzing and optimizing multi join query?

Tags: postgresql, join

I'm working on a project to familiarize myself with more complex sql, I have limited db experience.  I'm building a reporting application, and each report will have a series of questions and category types the user can select.

I plan to have multiple analytic functions, but to get off the ground I'm simply doing a select *.  The result I'd like to see in my app is a list of Report objects like
(java)

```
public class Report {
  // report table columns...
  List<Questions> questions;
  List<Cattype> catTypes;
}
```

I'm afraid doing this in one massive join'd query will suffer from cartesian explosion.

```
CREATE TABLE report (
  reportid bigint not null,
  useraccount varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  geotag geometry(POINT, 4326) default null,
  text varchar(256) not null,

  CONSTRAINT pk_report PRIMARY KEY (reportid),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geotag CHECK (((geometrytype(geotag) = 'POINT'::text) OR (geotag IS NULL))),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_geotag CHECK ((st_srid(geotag) = 4326))
);

create table cattype (
  cattypeid SERIAL,
  title varchar(64) not null,
  CONSTRAINT pk_cattype PRIMARY KEY (cattypeid),
  CONSTRAINT unique_cattype_title UNIQUE (title)
);

create table question (
  questionid SERIAL,
  title varchar(256) not null,
  CONSTRAINT pk_question PRIMARY KEY (questionid),
  CONSTRAINT unique_question_title UNIQUE (title)
);

create table report_cattype (
  id SERIAL,
  reportid bigint not null,
  cattypeid integer not null,

  CONSTRAINT pk_rc PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_rc_report FOREIGN KEY (reportid)
    REFERENCES report (reportid) match simple,
  CONSTRAINT fk_rc_cattype FOREIGN KEY (cattypeid)
    REFERENCES cattype (cattypeid) match simple
);

create table report_question (
  id SERIAL,
  reportid bigint not null,
  questionid integer not null,

  CONSTRAINT pk_rq PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_rq_report FOREIGN KEY (reportid)
    REFERENCES report (reportid) match simple,
  CONSTRAINT fk_rq_question FOREIGN KEY (questionid)
    REFERENCES question (questionid) MATCH SIMPLE
);

INSERT into cattype (title) values ('Water');
INSERT into cattype (title) values ('Fire');
INSERT into cattype (title) values ('Structural');

INSERT into question (title) values ('Damage visible from exterior?');
INSERT into question (title) values ('Damage visible in interior?');
INSERT into question (title) values ('Repair?');
INSERT into question (title) values ('Replace?');

insert into report values (1, 'user1', null, 'test1');
insert into report values (2, 'user1', null, 'test2');
insert into report values (3, 'user1', null, 'test3');
insert into report values (4, 'user1', null, 'test4');
insert into report values (5, 'user1', null, 'test5');
insert into report values (6, 'user1', null, 'test6');
insert into report values (7, 'user1', null, 'test7');
insert into report values (8, 'user1', null, 'test8');
insert into report values (9, 'user1', null, 'test9');
insert into report values (10, 'user1', null, 'test10');
insert into report values (11, 'user1', null, 'test11');
insert into report values (12, 'user1', null, 'test12');
insert into report values (13, 'user1', null, 'test13');
insert into report values (14, 'user1', null, 'test14');
insert into report values (15, 'user1', null, 'test15');

insert into report_cattype (reportid, cattypeid) values (1, 2);
insert into report_cattype (reportid, cattypeid) values (1, 3);
insert into report_cattype (reportid, cattypeid) values (2, 1);
insert into report_cattype (reportid, cattypeid) values (3, 3);

insert into report_question (reportid, questionid) values (1, 1);
insert into report_question (reportid, questionid) values (1, 2);
insert into report_question (reportid, questionid) values (1, 4);
insert into report_question (reportid, questionid) values (2, 2);
insert into report_question (reportid, questionid) values (2, 3);
insert into report_question (reportid, questionid) values (3, 1);
insert into report_question (reportid, questionid) values (3, 3);
```

Initial query looks like

```
select r.*, rc.*, cattype.*, rq.*, question.* from report r
  left join report_cattype as rc on (r.reportid = rc.reportid)
  left join cattype on (rc.cattypeid = cattype.cattypeid)
  left join report_question as rq on (r.reportid = rq.reportid)
  left join question on (rq.questionid = question.questionid)
```

Now I'm thinking I'm better off running multiple queries and combining them together in my application - Query all reports, then query table report_question or report_cattype for each report. Thoughts?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

Comment: You won't have a "Cartesian explosion" assuming those joins are well-formed, but I'm intrigued about what you are actually trying to do. What do you intend to do with the results in your application?

Comment: @seventyeightist It's a generic reporting capability, I could replace 'report' with 'form'.  With the results, my app would just be viewing or allowing users to bin them anyway they'd like

Comment: You really don't have a question here.  You want to do something unspecified, and want to know the best way to do it.  Make it do what you want first (perhaps on a reduced data set), then figure out if it is fast enough.  You can't tune a query you haven't written yet, and tuning a different query just because it is easier to write is a waste of time.